# Visual Studio Extensions development and wrong library version used

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm developing extension for VS 2015/2017. I'm using some external libraries like RestSharp version 105.2.3. Unfortunately some users get this exception:

```
"Could not load type 'RestSharp.Authenticators.IAuthenticator from assembly 'RestSharp, Version=105.0.0.0 ....".
```

I know exactly what happened but I have no idea how to fix it in VS extensions. It looks like they have installed another extension that uses RestSharp 105.0.0 and there is no binary compatibility with my version. It's loaded before my extension so my extension doesn't even try to load RestSharp because it's already there. I'm using `AssemblyResolve` event to resolve failed references but it looks like it's not even called because this reference can be loaded. Is there a way to force specific version of external library?

Also as far as I know binding redirects don't work in vs plugins.

Comment: Is RestSharp dll strong named?

Comment: @SergeyVlasov I dont think so. There is a separate nuget package RestSharp Signed but I'm using not signed version.